# element.firstChild.each() undefined

Tags: jquery, class, each

I am unable to catch firstChild.each() elements in the page.

```
jQuery(function() {
        $(".custom-link").firstChild.each(function(t,x) {
        if (/*$(x).attr('href').indexOf('isbn=' > -1) &&*/ $(x).attr('href').indexOf('isbn=&' == -1)) { //Check if the ISBN exists
        var href = $(x).attr('href');
        var isbn = href.substring((href.lastIndexOf('su=')+3),(href.lastIndexOf('su=')+16));});
```

I have used almost this exact line of code, with a different class, in a different app, and it worked fine. The only difference is the .firstChild function, which should be pretty straight forward.

I thought that maybe the issue was that the class elements are loaded after this code, so I attempted to wrap it in a .ready() function, but the issue remained the same.

According to the page source, there are 66 instances of this class in the page.

I also tried to use:

```
$(".custom-link:first-child").each(function(t,x) {
```

But the css :first-child command doesn't seem to work with a class selector.

I tried creating an array and using .each() on it:

```
var customlinks = $(".custom-link").firstChild;
customlinks.each(function(t,x) {
```

But I am receiving an "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'each' of undefined" because customlinks is still undefined.

Comment: `.firstChild` is a `javascript` function rather than `jquery` ,calling it like `document.querySelector('.custom-link').firstChild` should work for you , it unclear what you are doing as there is no html added, `.custom-link` should be the container when using javascript.

Comment: and calling `.each` on `firstChild` does not make sense as it returns only the first child, which is a single element, add the relevant `HTML` that is used with this script block

Comment: There's no `firstChild` property on jQuery collections. The pseudo-selector `:first-child` works the same way in jQuery as in CSS, in your example it would find all elements with the class `custom-link` **that is also** the first child element of its parent element. Perhaps what you're looking for is `.first()`?

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing jQuery and DOM functions. The jQuery equivalent is:

```
$(".custom-link > *:first-child").each(...);
```

You have to attach the `:first-child` pseudo-class to the element you want to select. `.custom-link:first-child` selects elements with `class="custom-link"` that are themselves the first child of their parent. `> *` matches the children of `.custom-link`, and then `:first-child` restricts it only to the first child of each.

You can actually shorten the it to

```
$(".custom-link > :first-child")
```

because `*` is the default there.

Comment: FYI, the `*` is redundant in that selector

Comment: Yeah, but it makes it easier to explain how it works. :)